# Akavache 5.0 values are null

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, xamarin.forms, akavache

I am using Akavache 5.0 with Xamarin.Forms.  Out of nowhere my cache stopped working.  I am using Blobcache.LocalMachine to save a key with an object.  For the last year it has worked and now on restart of the app it still has the keys stored and brings back objects with all of the values being null.  I have also tried this using Blobcache.UserAccount and the same results.

On my App.cs Init()  i set the name for Blobcache and call EnsureInitialize as well.

Yes I have checked that my Visual Studio settings are set to keep the cache on restart for android.  I have deployed my app to the google play beta store and still the same results.

I am also using Azure Mobile Service Client which I have read can cause some issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem, could you please share a basic demo that could reproduce this problem? or post the code that you  save and retrieving data.

Comment: I tried a demo project and it works fine.  It used to work fine on both of my apps (I have two seperate ones) and now both only show the keys with null values.

Comment: have you fixed your problem? it happened to me once as well but i cant reproduce it now again